# How to edit the size of a ternary plot created in R?

Tags: r, plot, ternary

Thank you in advanced for reading my question, I am new to R and stackedoverflow. Please bare with me and forgive me if I have made any mistakes with the formatting of this post.

My Question: How to edit the size of a ternary plot created in R?

I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69436531/how-to-create-soil-texture-ternary-plot) where someone provided an awesome answer to someone who was looking to create a ternary plot for soil texture classification. After spending some time reading through and playing around with the code in his answer, I have also managed to create a ternary plot with the same input data.

However, despite using the same code, the plot I am receiving in R is formatted differently. By this I mean, it seams as if the size of my ternary plot is smaller than the one plotted by the author of code.

I have tried reading through the source code of the function (part of it had to be changed to improve the format of the plot, this is explained in the answer provided) to better understand it, but I cannot find anything that I understand to be responsible for size. I have attached two images below to demonstrate the difference.

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8hro.png)
[Authors output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFSUo.png)

Below I have attached the code I am working with from the original post

```
area <- c('S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','S6','S7','S8')
sand <- c(76.4,56.9,61.7,64.5,71,70.1,60.5,53.7)
silt<-c(9.3,23.1,23,17.4,13.5,13.4,21.1,30.6)
clay<-c(14.3, 20,15.4,18,15.5,16.6,18.4,15.7)
my_data<-data.frame(area,sand,silt,clay)

library(plotrix)
Pracsoil <- function (soiltexture = NULL, main = "", at = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.1), 
                      axis.labels = c("percent sand", "percent silt", "percent clay"), 
                      tick.labels = list(l = seq(10, 90, by = 10), r = seq(10, 
                                                                           90, by = 10), b = seq(10, 90, by = 10)), show.names = TRUE, 
                      show.lines = TRUE, col.names = "gray", bg.names = par("bg"), 
                      show.grid = FALSE, col.axis = "black", col.lines = "gray", 
                      col.grid = "gray", lty.grid = 3, show.legend = FALSE, label.points = FALSE, 
                      point.labels = NULL, col.symbols = "black", pch = par("pch"), 
                      ...) 
{
  par(xpd = TRUE)
  triax.plot(x = NULL, main = main, at = at, axis.labels = axis.labels, 
             tick.labels = tick.labels, col.axis = col.axis, show.grid = show.grid, 
             col.grid = col.grid, lty.grid = lty.grid)
  arrows(0.12, 0.41, 0.22, 0.57, length = 0.15)
  arrows(0.78, 0.57, 0.88, 0.41, length = 0.15)
  arrows(0.6, -0.1, 0.38, -0.1, length = 0.15)
  if (show.lines) {
    triax.segments <- function(h1, h3, t1, t3, col) {
      segments(1 - h1 - h3/2, h3 * sin(pi/3), 1 - t1 - 
                 t3/2, t3 * sin(pi/3), col = col)
    }
    h1 <- c(85, 70, 80, 52, 52, 50, 20, 8, 52, 45, 45, 65, 
            45, 20, 20)/100
    h3 <- c(0, 0, 20, 20, 7, 0, 0, 12, 20, 27, 27, 35, 40, 
            27, 40)/100
    t1 <- c(90, 85, 52, 52, 43, 23, 8, 0, 45, 0, 45, 45, 
            0, 20, 0)/100
    t3 <- c(10, 15, 20, 7, 7, 27, 12, 12, 27, 27, 55, 35, 
            40, 40, 60)/100
    triax.segments(h1, h3, t1, t3, col.lines)
  }
  if (show.names) {
    xpos <- c(0.5, 0.7, 0.7, 0.73, 0.73, 0.5, 0.275, 0.275, 
              0.27, 0.27, 0.25, 0.135, 0.18, 0.055, 0.49, 0.72, 
              0.9)
    ypos <- c(0.66, 0.49, 0.44, 0.36, 0.32, 0.35, 0.43, 0.39, 
              0.3, 0.26, 0.13, 0.072, 0.032, 0.024, 0.18, 0.15, 
              0.06) * sin(pi/3)
    snames <- c("clay", "silty", "clay", "silty clay", "loam", 
                "clay loam", "sandy", "clay", "sandy clay", "loam", 
                "sandy loam", "loamy", "sand", "sand", "loam", "silt loam", 
                "silt")
    text(xpos, ypos, labels=snames)
  }
  par(xpd = FALSE)
  if (is.null(soiltexture)) 
    return(NULL)
  soilpoints <- triax.points(soiltexture, show.legend = show.legend, 
                             label.points = label.points, point.labels = point.labels, 
                             col.symbols = col.symbols, pch = pch, ...)
  invisible(soilpoints)
}
Pracsoil(my_data[,2:4],col.symbols=1:8,bg.symbols=1:8,point.labels=my_data$area,pch=21,col.grid=5)
legend( x=1, 
        legend=my_data$area,
        col=1:8, 
        fill=1:8 )
```

I Have tried googling different characters to understand what each bit means in the code but I can only find how to change the size of the points on the plot and not the plot itself. Does anyone know how I would be able to alter the sizing to match that of the authors output?

Comment: Generally, the size of the plot is not determined by the code you use to plot it, but by the output device.  Can I check - are you using R on its own, or in an IDE like RStudio (Posit)?

Comment: There is a `mar = ` argument for function `plotrix::triax.plot()` for "Margins for the triangle plot. [See function documentation here](https://rdrr.io/cran/plotrix/man/triax.plot.html). Maybe trying adjusting that value and see if produces any results for you.

Comment: It can take some getting used to, but in R, the results of plotting do not scale the way that other desktop applications do. If you make your plotting device taller, the text will stay the same size and the plotting shapes will change dimension. Try making your plotting window larger, and perhaps make it tall and thin rather than short and wide. You will see what I mean.

Comment: @AllanCameron this fixed it, I cant believe it was something so simple and innocuous. Thank you so much for the assistance.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen in an IDE, I have started with Rstudio. You and another commenter were correct, I just needed to adjust the display window. I chuckled at myself. Thank you for the time!

Comment: @Quinton.Quagliano thank you for that suggestion, I will look through the function documentation for additional information. The problem has been solved though, I just needed to adjust the output display in Rstudio... we live and we learn. All the best!

Comment: @Rubeus Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: @Rubeus you can also export it appropriately using `pdf` or `png`, etc with an appropriate height and width - this will still show up funky in your Rstudio window but export with he correct dimensions - (ie., use `pdf("your_file_path/figure_name.pdf", height = 8, width = 8); Pracsoil(my_data[,2:4], col.symbols = 1:8, bg.symbols = 1:8, point.labels = my_data$area, pch = 21, col.grid = 5); legend(x = 1, legend = my_data$area, col = 1:8, fill = 1:8 ); dev.off()`